# Set a value to Duration in MSProject

Tags: vba, duration, ms-project

I can't seem to assign a value to Duration field in MSProject by using VBA.
Probably has something to do with types?
Tsk.Duration = (rate1)
--while rate 1 is defined as long and equals 14

the value that appears is 0.03 (in days). Why not 14 days???
Tsk.Duration is Variant/Long

Thanks in advance,
Sivan

Answer (score 2):

The [Duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.duration) of a task is stored in minutes, not days. To set a duration of 14 days use:

`Tsk.Duration = 14 * 8 * 60`.